# Juniper fails to launch

Tags: vpn

I am trying to VPN to my college network but I am having some problems.
My system is Ubuntu 14.04 and the browser is Firefox 35.0.1. When I click on `Network Connect - Start` Juniper Network Connect does not launch and I am redirected back on the same page without any error message.
I installed Java 8 update 31 as I thought that was the culprit. Please see below the configuration of Java on my system:

> Selection    Path                                     Priority
>   Status
>   ------------------------------------------------------------   0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   14        auto mode   1
>   /usr/java32/jre1.7.0_03/bin/java          10        manual mode   2
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   14        manual mode
>   * 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   13        manual mode

I then found out on Juniper website that Java 32-bit is required to run Juniper on Ubuntu 64-bit - see link http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25230.
I followed the instructions there and installed java32 and all the libraries - see output of `update-alternatives --display java`:

> java - manual mode   link currently points to
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
>   /usr/java32/jre1.7.0_03/bin/java - priority 10
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 14   slave
>   java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 13   slave
>   java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz Current
>   'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java'.

I also installed IcedTea 7.

I added the websites of my college to the exception list of both Java Control Panel security and Firefox Preferences Security.

Can you please help me resolve the problem preventing Juniper from starting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from the x64 arch.
You could try the solution described here : http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html
It will download and use the 32 bits version of the ncsvc exec.

It worked very well for me.